# Different layouts for different Android versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

Although it seems like stupid question, I'm wondering if there is another elegant way to handle my design problem rather than just to create two separate layouts
My App is supposed to have different custom layouts for ongoing notifications for Marshmallow and Nougat versions. The straightforward way, as I said, is to create two different XML files and load them base on the runtime platform. Is there any another approaches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are supposed to create different xml-Files for different versions, Android's Resource Management is designed like this.
Check this link for more information https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: cool, there is Platform Version (API level) Qualifier Values, that's what I missed

Comment: @DenisVolohsin: Use `-vNNN`, where `NNN` is an API level. So, `res/layout-v23/notification.xml` would be used on API Level 23+ devices, and `res/layout/notification.xml` would be used on API Level 1-22 devices.

Comment: If you right click the resources directory in android studio you can create a new Android Resource Directory where you can choose your qualifiers and android studio names the folder right for you